Exoplayer can't play rtp url
I'm streaming a video using the RTP/TCP protocol. VLC media player works perfectly with the stream URL, but ExoPlayer displays a black screen.
playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView)
    val renderersFactory =
        DefaultRenderersFactory(this).forceEnableMediaCodecAsynchronousQueueing()
    val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        .setAllocator(DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE))
        .setBufferDurationsMs(30_000, 60_000, 3_000, 6_000)
        .setTargetBufferBytes(C.LENGTH_UNSET)
        .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true)
        .build()
    player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this, renderersFactory)
        .setLoadControl(loadControl)
        .build()
    playerView?.setPlayer(player)

    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri("rtp://239.100.0.1:8433")
        .build()
    val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory{UdpDataSource()}
        .createMediaSource(mediaItem)

    player?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
    player?.prepare()
    player?.playWhenReady = true

I've tested with both ExoPlayer 2 and ExoPlayer 3, but the issue persists (black screen).
